# Google Maps JS API v3 – componentRestriction "locality" not working anymore

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am using Geocoder to search for streets within a given city and a given country. In my case I am searching in Germany, Munich only. But since today (?) this Geocoder `componentRestriction` do not work anymore.

It searches withing germany, that working well. But Geocoder also returns results that are not within Munich.

Here is s fiddle example: On click on the Search Button it should point to Munich, Karlstraße. But it points to Dusseldorf, Karlstraße. Even with

```
'componentRestrictions': {
     'country': 'DE', 'locality': 'München'
 }
```

I did work – fore sure. And in the docs I did not found anything else / new.

https://jsfiddle.net/8e6xh7sc/110/

Comment: Is [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq#trbl_component_filtering) what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The following components may be used to influence results, but will not be enforced:

route matches the long or short name of a route.

locality matches against locality and sublocality types.

administrative_area matches all the administrative_area levels.

as stated here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

So to answer your question, yes the response will be restricted only to "DE" Germany, but only "influenced" to a city but not restricted at all, so yes is normal that you are also having results in another city

Comment: I am 100 percent sure that locality restricts the search to only this city at the moment when I had developed this thing. It is in use for over 2 years now and did always only search within Munich.

Comment: I don't now 2 years ago...but I am 100 % sure that today It is like this, remember that Google its constantly changing its products. anyway I hoped this helped. good luck

Comment: All returned results match all component filter. Also locality is a component to filter the results. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering as stated there (in german docs).

Comment: what is stated there? I just seeing the same thing that i posted you (I am seeing the English docs since I cannot read German) but anyway another tip would be: always read the english documentation, since in the process of traduction, documentations in another language could take more time to be updated or bring outdated errors

Comment: maybe you belive me know https:/issuetracker.google.com/issues/72122489